# How to enable MobileFirst Analytic https port in liberty profile

Tags: https, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, server.xml, mobilefirst-analytics

Good day,

I am referring this article to set up the MobileFirst Analytic server in Liberty:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.analytics.doc/analytics/t_installing_on_liberty.html?view=embed

The server is up with only http port, but not https port.

I check with `netstat -plunt` command, also only saw the http port is listening.

The following is the http endpoint in my server.xml:

```
<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
              httpPort="9081"
              httpsPort="9444" host="*" />
```

Anything I miss configure?

Comment: When you access via https port ( 9444) , what do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you define keystore in your server.xml? Similar issue discussed here https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/261762/liberty-profile-not-binding-https-port.html . Please add keystore and check whether https enabled.